# What is the meaning of "I weigh it off on 20 cents on the dollar"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Hank telling to Andy that he wants to knock down a jewellery shop:

> Hank: Well, you need money. So do I. Let's solve it.
>
> Andy: What are you talking about?
>
> Hank: Well, there's a place we can knock off. Know it like the back of
>   our hand. Easiest money you'll ever get.
>
> Andy:: What are you saying?
>
> Hank: It's worth about 600 grand. And it's insured, so it's a
>   victimless crime. I offer that in case your faggoty little conscience
>   bothers you. **I weigh it off on 20 cents on the dollar**. That's 60 grand
>   each. Give or take.

Comment: "Knock a place off* means to rob the place. "At 20 cents on the dollar" means at 20% of its value. Why the stolen goods are "weighed off" is not clear. Is the thing they're stealing something that is sold by weight?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

- "X cents on the dollar" - you will get only X cents per dollar worth of something, see [What does it mean to “pay X on the dollar”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/what-does-it-mean-to-pay-x-on-the-dollar)
- "I weight it off" - I cannot find a definition, but from the context, Hanks approximates how much they can get: "I guess" or "I weight it in my mind and I think that..."

Summary: Hank expect that they can sell robbed jewelry at 20 cents per dollar.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - better?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the expression "to weigh off" is referring to old-fashioned (weighing) scales, where one would determine the weight of something by "weighing it off" with a series of small weights - i.e. placing weights of various quantities on one side of the scales until the weights balanced, then recording the value of the weights placed.

[image: old weighing scales]

Therefore, we can deduce that "to weigh off on *x*" means "to be measured as *x*". In this case, I interpret

> I weigh it off on 20 cents on the dollar.

as

> I measure [the amount of money we'll get] to be 20 cents on the dollar [i.e. 20 cents for every dollar, or 20% of the original net worth].

FYI, this isn't exactly a common idiom in modern-day English (I'm a native speaker, and this is the first time I've heard it, so I don't know how much credibility that gives me... :P)